# How to compare a DATETIME to a VARCHAR date that can have different lengths?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I have to compare two dates of birth from different tables.

- column `C.date_of_birth` is of type `DATETIME`
- column `R.dob` is a date stored as `VARCHAR`, but with no leading zeroes on the month or day parts to make its length consistent (<--that's the tough part).

I've gotten as close as this:

```
where R.dob <> convert(varchar, cast(C.date_of_birth as DATE), 101)
```

but that returns too many rows because `1/5/1923` in `R.dob` does not match `01/05/1923` in `C.date_of_birth`.

How can I format `R.dob` so it can correctly be compared to `C.date_of_birth`?

Thank you.

Comment: why is a datetime stored as varchar? If you can, fix the cause not the symptoms.

Comment: ...failing that convert the varchar to date (not the other way round) and then compare two dates.

Comment: And what is proper syntax of converting varchar to date?  I have tried everything i can think of, and most give me the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."  I have tried CAST(R.dob as DATETIME2), CONVERT(datetime, R.dob, 101), and every other combination I can think of.  Sorry--long day.

Comment: @user477526: the proper syntax would be `CAST(r.dob AS DATE)` if you're only interested in the date portion (not time). **HOWEVER:** the bigger problem I see is that your `R.dob` representation of a date is language/regional settings dependent - and that's just hell. I agree with Mitch: you gotta fix the **root problem** and make this a `DATE` column - otherwise you'll be struggling and pulling out your hair for the rest of your days....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your varchar as a datetime.  For instance, the result of this:

```
select cast('1/5/1923' as datetime)
```

Would be `1923-01-05 00:00:00.000`

Then you can just use `DATEDIFF()` to compare them to see which are equal to the day (or whatever interval you so desire).

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
declare @date_of_birth datetime = '1923-01-05',
        @dob varchar(10) = '01/05/1923'

select  @date_of_birth,
        CONVERT(datetime, @dob, 101), -- 101: mm/dd/yyyy
        case    when @date_of_birth = CONVERT(datetime, @dob, 111)
                then 1 else 0
        end result
```

Comment: Thank you, Rubens.  I tried CONVERT(datetime, R.dob, 101), but it gives me "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" error.  Btw, R.dob is stored as VARCHAR(4096).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to cast the varchar field to date and do the comparison; for example all of this formats can be easily be converted to date type:

```
SELECT cast ( '1/1/2011' as date) col1
union
SELECT cast ( '01/11/2011' as date) col1
union
SELECT cast ( 'Oct 7 2011' as date) col1
union
SELECT cast ( '2011-02-23' as date) col1
```

Outputs:

```
col1
----------
2011-01-01
2011-01-11
2011-02-23
2011-10-07
```

So in your query you can compare dates to dates.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, first option would be to change the data type of `R.Dob` to `Date`.

Otherwise you should cast your `varchar` to a `date` and by your comments you get an error doing that. The reason for that is probably because you have invalid dates in the column. You could make use of the [isdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function to figure out what rows have invalid dates.

Another reason could be that your SQL Server does not know how to interpret your date strings.
I don't know how to interpret this value `1/5/1923` so how could SQL Server know?

Use [set dateformat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) to tell SQL Server how to interpret the date string.

```
set dateformat mdy
select cast('1/5/1923' as date)

set dateformat dmy
select cast('1/5/1923' as date)
```

Result:

```
----------
1923-01-05

----------
1923-05-01
```